# Order feed in CSV format

Tags: cartthrob

I need to set up an order feed to supply order details to a reviews website, it has to have specific field names and be in CSV format.

Is there an option to do this in cartthrob? Or will I need to create a template, if so are there tags available for orders?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to make a template and use tags, or use something like this: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajw-export

Orders are just channel entries, so you can do a standard `exp:channel:entries` loop with the `channel=` parameter filled in to output them.

Answer (score 0):

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-export can be a good option to export the data.
The best part is, You don't need to create a templates or write any query here. It is simply select and download.